# Menu off canvas bug mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know if it's really a bug, but what happens is:
I'm in mobile and activate my offcanvas menu if I scroll down to the bottom of the page the menu is cutted and when the scroll finish he backs to the normal, I think that it's because I'm using position fixed, I'm putting a print that I took on my cellphone.My server of tests is http://tiagotestes.esy.es/portfolio (PS: The images used there aren't mine, I just used for tests) I really don't know how to solve that, looks like it's a rendering problem...

Print:

[image]

HTML:

```
<nav class="off-canvas" id="offcanvas">
         <ul class="itens">
            <a href="#banner" id="offlinkbanner">
               <li class="off-item">
                  <h2>Inicio</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#sobremim">
               <li class="off-item">
                  <h2>Sobre Mim</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#habilidades">
               <li class="off-item">
                  <h2>Habilidades</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#portfolio">
               <li class="off-item">
                  <h2>Portfólio</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#contato">
               <li class="off-item">
                  <h2>Contato</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
         </ul>
      </nav>
```

Css:

```
.off-canvas{
  transition: all .4s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
  -o-transition: all .4s linear;
  padding-top: 50px;
  left: -300px;
  background-color: #292929;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 9;

}
```

Js that makes the magic:

```
function mostraCanvas(offcanvas, toggle, expand) {
    offcanvas.css("left", "0");
   // expand.css("display", "inline");
   // toggle.css("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: So you want the menu to slide from left and cover the whole screen?

Comment: @NasirT, almost the full screen, but the style isn't the problem, the menu are the way that I wanted, but, this bug when I scroll is so annoying :/. Have you seen the website on the url that I posted? There U can reproduce the bug on you cellphone.

Comment: I understand now. I have put in an answer with 3 possibilities including your problem which i think is scenario # 2. Can you try them and see if it works.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this bug in firefox and chrome (shrinking the windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i think you should change in your code if i am understanding you correctly.

**Scenario 1:**

You want the offcanvas menu to cover the whole screen width when open. For that you need to make the following changes.

In the `@media only screen and (max-width: 1021px) .off-canvas` css class:

1. Change `width:250px;` to `width:100vw;`
2. Add `min-width:250px;`.
3. Change `height:100%;` to `height:100vh;`

In the scripts.js file, the function `escondeCanvas(offcanvas, toggle, expand)`, change the `offcanvas.css("left", "-300px");` to `offcanvas.css("left", "-100vw");`

The above changes will make the menu cover the whole screen width and height wise.

**Scenario 2:**

When you scroll in mobile the first time after load. The menu seems to shift to top and leave a blank space at the bottom and when the scroll stops the blank space is filled by the gray background.

I believe this is due to the address bar disappearing in mobile when you scroll up on any web page. In the `@media only screen and (max-width: 1021px) .off-canvas` css class, Change `height:100%;` to `height:100vh;`. And just to make sure, add `padding-bottom: 50px;`.

***Detail on Scenario 1 and 2 answers: vw and vh are viewport units. They take into account the full screen size of the device without any element or property effecting it. E.g. 100% unit may only use the space within the element it is set for where as 100vh or 100vw is the full screen height or width respectively of the device the page is loaded on.***

**Scenario 3:** 
You want to keep the width and height as default i.e. but when you scroll down with the menu open, the top gray menu layer that toggle background color to transparent and back based on top scroll shows up which should only show up when the menu is not open.

You need to make changes in the function `trocaNav(navbar, imgtoggle, topo, posicao, itensmenu)` in the script file to check and change the background color of the topo div from transparent to gray only if the menu is open. Example logic  to check the menu open you can put condition on the `off-canvas` left margin. If the left is 0 then the menu is open and if the left is -300px or undefined then the menu is closed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding `height:100vh;` the bug was solved, just to be clear, my problem was when I activate de menu and, with him activated I scroll down de page, then, the bottom were cutted, The moviment  "left x right" is ok, you have Idea why It was happening? Whats the difference between height: 100%; and height: 100vh;??

Comment: I have updated my answer in Scenario 2. It was due to the address bar being hidden by the mobile browser when you scroll on any page and that left the menu height to recalculate once the scroll stopped. vh is view port height so it always covers the whole mobile screen height without the address bar or any other element effecting it. Also i think adding padding-bottom would also solve the issue but best to use efficient code.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as correct and vote please as it helped you out. Thanks. Happy coding.